# How do I understand $f \equiv 1$ as the limit of step functions?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am a beginner in Lebesgue Integral and I am learning Analysis from Tomorrow Apostol's *Mathematical Analysis*.   Apostol gives following definition of step function

> A function $s$, defined on compact interval $[a, b]$, is called a *step function* if there is a partition $P = \{ x_0, x_1, \dotsc, x_n\}$ on $[a, b]$ such that $s$ is constant on every open subinterval $s(x) = c_{k}$ if $x$ belongs to $( x_{k-1} , x_{ k} )$ .

On page 279 Apostol writes constant function $f=1$ is limit of step functions on real line.

But I am unable to construct any  sequence of step functions that tends to $f=1$, although definition is clear.

I don't have any instructor to help me as it was not taught in our class and I am self studying.

Can anyone please construct a set of step functions so that I am able to clear this concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just let the function $f_n$ take the value $1$ on $[-n,n]$ and zero elsewhere? Then the constant function $f\equiv 1$ is the pointwise limit of the sequence of functions $f_n$, and each of these $f_n$ are of the desired form.

Comment: But in your answer, each $f_n$ is not compactly defined as stated in the definition.  I am not sure whether this is a nuance Apostol didn't mean to forget.  And frankly, what kind of limits is Apostol using?

Comment: However, set-theoretically, you can define each $f_n$ as a set (well, a function is a set) by saying $f_n:=[-n,+n]\times\{1\}$ for each $n=1,2,3,\ldots$.  Then, $f_1\subseteq f_2\subseteq f_3\subseteq \ldots$, and each $f_n$ is compactly defined.  Then, $f:=\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{>0}}\,f_n=\mathbb{R}\times\{1\}$ is the required constant function.  Note that $f$ is the direct limit of $\left(f_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ under the natural inclusion maps.  However, I don't think this is what Apostal had in mind either.

Comment: Apostol later states that it is convenient to remove the restriction that the domain of a step function be compact, and does so by simply requiring the existence of a compact interval $[a,b]$ such that the restriction of the function to that interval is a step function (in the original sense), and the function vanishes outside of that interval. This is precisely what I have used. In that case, we usually say that the function is "compactly supported".

Comment: Note too that it doesn't make sense for a sequence of functions to converge pointwise to another function unless all of the functions involved have the same domain. In particular, each of the $f_n$ should be defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: This example should serve as a reminder to anyone doubting Apostol's approach. When I studied this for the first time from Apostol I was having a hard time dealing with functions on unbounded intervals. By choosing $[-n, n] $ we get an unbounded interval in the limit. By using limits Lebesgue integrals handles unbounded functions on unbounded intervals without any special treatment (compare with improper Riemann integrals).